# Why is my java if statement not working and giving me this error: "bad operand types for binary operator '&&'"?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, operators

I have this code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
    if (hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || 'B' && hand[i].charAt(1) == 'C') 
        System.out.println(hand[i]);
        }
```

Basically what I want this to do is if the character at index 0 in each array element is either A or B, AND the character at the second index in each array element is C, I want those elements to be printed.  It works with one character, but when I put the or in the first part, it gives me this error: "bad operand types for binary operator '&&'".  How do I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write

```
hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || 'B'
```

perhaps you meant to write

```
hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || hand[i].charAt(0) == 'B'
```

BTW You can write

```
"AB".indexOf(hand[i].charAt(0)) >= 0
```

This way you can add many more letters if you like.

However the clearest way to write the whole thing might be

```
if (hand[i].startsWith("AC") || hand[i].startsWith("BC"))
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @jdc987 I suspect `startsWith` is the best alternative

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

```
hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || 'B'
```

Logical OR does not work the way you think it does.  Use:

```
hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || hand[i].charAt(0) == 'B'
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax. Each boolean operator (`||`, `&&`, etc.) works only with boolean values. No ints (like in C) and definetely no chars.

```
if (hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || 'B' && hand[i].charAt(1) == 'C')
```

should be

```
if ((hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || hand[i].charAt(0) == 'B') && hand[i].charAt(1) == 'C')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator (and `&&`) only works with `boolean` values, not `char` values.  What this means is that you need to explicitly write each comparison with each character.

Change:

```
hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || 'B'
```

to

```
(hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || hand[i].charAt(0) == 'B')
```

The "or" condition is enclosed in parentheses so it's evaluated before the `&&`, which is what I believe you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is used to compare booleans, you are passing a char instead of a boolean.

```
if (hand[i].charAt(0) == 'A' || hand[i].charAt(0) == 'B' && hand[i].charAt(1) == 'C') 
        System.out.println(hand[i]);
        }
```